# Text Box Picker

Tags: objective-c, ios, textbox, uipickerview

Im practicing using a picker to input values into a text field. Ive tried to adapt some code found on here to present a picker when text box is touched to fill out text field.  The text boxes were built in code [SOURCE](http://pastie.org/1962865) and I would like to build the text boxes in IB. However this has stopped the presentation picker view, and presents only the keyboard now instead

Perhaps someone would point me in the right direction here.  My code:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface pick2 : UIViewController

<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {
UIPickerView *locationsPicker;
UIToolbar    *accessoryView;

UITextField *text1;


NSArray      *locations;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIPickerView *locationsPicker;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIToolbar *accessoryView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *text1;

- (void)onLocationSelection;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "pick2.h"

@interface pick2 ()

@end

@implementation pick2
@synthesize text1;

- (UIPickerView *)locationsPicker {
if ( locationsPicker == nil ) {
    locationsPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    locationsPicker.delegate = self;
    locationsPicker.dataSource = self;
    locationsPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
}

    return locationsPicker;
}

- (UIToolbar *)accessoryView {
if ( accessoryView == nil ) {
    accessoryView = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                                   target:self
                                                                                   action:@selector(onLocationSelection)];
    [accessoryView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:doneButton]];
}

return accessoryView;
}

 #pragma mark - Memory management



  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  }

#pragma mark - View lifecycle



- (void)onLocationSelection {
NSInteger row = [self.locationsPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];

( [text1 isFirstResponder] ); {
    text1.text = [locations objectAtIndex:row];
    [text1 resignFirstResponder];
}
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - picker view delegate/datasource

- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row     forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [locations objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:     (NSInteger)component {
return [locations count];
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {

locations = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"New York", @"Chicago", @"Memphis",  @"California", @"Seattle",@"London",@"Paris", nil]; 


[super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setText1:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];

}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is give the inputView of your UITextField as object of your pickerview.

```
text1.inputView  = locationsPicker;
```

tapping on the UITextField will present the pickerview now.

Comment: Thanks for that, no matter where I put that code I just get the standard keyboard presented?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this by using IB to build text boxes and

`NSInteger selectedRow = [select selectedRowInComponent:0];
    text1.text = [arrStatus objectAtIndex: selectedRow];
    [text1 resignFirstResponder];`

To retrive text value